# getting correlation value from certain column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot

let say ratings.head()

```
critic  title   rating
0   Jack Matthews   Lady in the Water   3.0
1   Jack Matthews   Snakes on a Plane   4.0
2   Jack Matthews   You Me and Dupree   3.5
3   Jack Matthews   Superman Returns    5.0
4   Jack Matthews   The Night Listener  3.0
```

And I want to get an correlation value like

```
title   Just My Luck    Lady in the Water   Snakes on a Plane   Superman Returns    The Night Listener  You Me and Dupree

Just My Luck    1.000000    -0.944911   -0.333333   -0.422890   0.555556    -0.485662
Lady in the Water   -0.944911   1.000000    0.577350    0.404226    NaN 0.333333
Snakes on a Plane   -0.333333   0.577350    1.000000    -0.101929   -0.408248   -0.645497
Superman Returns    -0.422890   0.404226    -0.101929   1.000000    -0.062500   0.657952
The Night Listener  0.555556    NaN -0.408248   -0.062500   1.000000    -0.250000
You Me and Dupree   -0.485662   0.333333    -0.645497   0.657952    -0.250000   1.000000
```

in python I'm trying to use the pivot but it  removes the 0,1,2,3,4 from the first table.

how to get a correlation table like above using pandas?

Comment: Take the result of your pivot code, and then do: `df = df.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='critic', columns='title', values='rating').corr()
```

Alternative with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['critic','title'])['rating'].unstack().corr()
```